# Passing a list to freemarker

Tags: java, list, freemarker

**Java File**

```
for(..){
 java.util.List opslist = new ArrayList();
 opr.setOperationName(operation.getName()); //gets operation name (iterate and get n no of names) sets it to opr
 System.out.println(opr.getOperationName());//gets all the set values n prints it(jus to chack that all values r getting set)
 opslist.add(opr.getOperationName());//putting those valies into a list
 datamodel.put("opslist", opslist.toArray(new String[]{}));//putting it into a hash map with key as opslist and value as opslist object
}
```

**Freemarker Template**

```
<#list opslist as x> //read the values from the key "opslist" (gets only one value)
 ${x} //print values one by one(it prints only one value) </#list>
```

**output of the java file is a**

```
get
set
value
usage
```

**output of Freemarket template is**

```
usage
```

Why is only last value getting printed?
Can someone tell me the right way to do inside freemarker template?

Comment: Add code in [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you are creating a new opslist for each element in your list. in this way only the last element is passed to freemarker.
just put List opslist = new ArrayList(); in front of the for loop

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are creating a new list in every iteration of the for loop. Also, you are adding 4 lists for the same key, in datamodel map. It should be corrected as below:

```
    java.util.List opslist = new ArrayList();

    for(..){
        opr.setOperationName(operation.getName()); //gets operation name (iterate and get n no of names) sets it to opr

        System.out.println(opr.getOperationName());//gets all the set values n prints it(jus to chack that all values r getting set)

        opslist.add(opr.getOperationName());//putting those valies into a list
    }     

    datamodel.put("opslist", opslist.toArray(new String[]{}));//putting it into a hash map with key as opslist and value as opslist object
```